# Launching a Dialog window needs to take fresh values in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, static, launch

I'm new to WPF. I took a static variable as I want to retain the value when I open a dialog window but when i open it again as it is a static variable it is having previous values. So is there any way that i can destroy the static memory when every time I opens a window

Note: It needs to be static because I want to retain the value between function calls.

Comment: Create your dailog window constructor with params

Answer (score 0):

Use a static class and define static variables for it so that the values are the same everywhere during the project. I will give a complete example of this below.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
  public Window1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     MemoryData.State = "Window1 activated";
  }
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    Window2 wnd= new Window2();
    wnd.ShowDialog();
    //Returned Window2
    MessageBox.Show(MemoryData.State);
  }      
}

public partial class Window2 : Window
{
  public Window2()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     MemoryData.State = "Window2 activated";
     MessageBox.Show(MemoryData.State);
     MemoryData.State = "Returned Window2";
  } 
}

public static class MemoryData
{
   public static string State { get; set; }
}
```